# Acknowledging benign type casts in C

Tags: c, casting, warnings, type-conversion

I have long struggled with how best to deal with warnings for implicit type coercions in C.

Let's start off with a non-exhaustive list of examples. Compilers tend to vary widely in how pedantic they are.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* Truncation from 'const int' to 'float' */
    float a = 16777217;
    /* Potential loss of sign in conversion from `int' to `unsigned int' */
    unsigned int b = 1;
    /* Conversion from 'int' to 'char', possible loss of data */
    int c = 1;
    char d = c;
    /* Conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data */
    uint16_t e = 1;
    uint8_t f = e >> 8;
    /* Pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness */
    unsigned int *g = &argc;
    /* Initialization from incompatible pointer type (technically an error) */
    const char *const *h = argv;
    /* Different 'volatile' qualifiers */
    const volatile char *i = *argv;
    strlen(i);
    /* Generates a warning in an old embedded C compiler. No off-hand reference. */
    char *j = malloc(1);
    return 0;
}
```

In principle these are beneficial and often reveal real bugs. The problem is that once discovered my strategy for acknowledging them has generally either been through over-specified type-casts, a cure worse than the disease if ever there was one, or by reducing the warning level or selectively disabling particularly common warnings through #pragmas. The latter remedy is of course not possible if you're forced to work under draconian coding standards, such as MISRA C.

More advanced static analysis tools generally offer some mechanism for indicating false-positives which C compilers rarely seem to, and in any event such warning numbers are far from portable.

What is the recommended best-practice here?

I think I want something along the lines of const_cast in C++, plus unsigned_cast, demotion_cast, volatile_cast and what have you.

Lastly I apologize if this has already been asked, I imagine it has but was only able to find questions dealing with specific warnings rather the overarching problem.

Comment: The first one is not benign; it really does result in a loss of precision.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The question is what do when you've determined that the loss is acceptable (and the right-hand side is a variable.)

Comment: @doynax: I agree that overspecified type casts are annoying and can introduce more bugs than they solve.  I don't know what solution can really exist, though, unless or until people move toward languages which break free of 1970s-style expression-type evaluation.  I wish languages had a syntax for "cast to X", "cast from X", and "cast from Y to X", with a rule that implicit conversions would be very tightly restricted on the specified side of a cast, so that e.g. `x=(->float)someValue;` would fail if `x` was a type other than `float` (e.g. `double`).

Comment: @supercat: I'm not holding up much hope for my field adopting any new languages beyond C within the next century. C11 generics seem more like a cruel joke than a real feature at a time when virtually no one has even gotten around to C99 yet :(

Comment: @doynax: If "integer" types were split into "algebraic ring" types (with defined wrapping behavior) and "number" types (which represent numeric quantities"), and the largest "number" type was signed, a language could adopt a rule that any operation on numbers whose intermediate results would fit in the largest numeric type would yield the same results as if the largest numeric type were used for all subexpressions that were not coerced to smaller types; implementing such a rule efficiently might have been hard for 1970s' compilers, but would be relatively trivial today.

Comment: @doynax: I consider it ludicrous that in a "modern" language like C#, given the statement `longvar = intvar1+1;`, a compiler could generate code that throw an exception if `intvar1` equals 2147483647, or that would wrap to -2147483648 in that case, but would not be allowed to set `longvar` to 2147483648 even though a programmer would almost certainly prefer that to a trap, and would most likely prefer that to wrapping behavior.

Comment: @supercat: Frankly for most day-to-day work of most programmers dynamic arbitrary-precision arithmetic is fast enough. However there will always be exceptions where you need performance and where you would like these types tight static type/range checks (my last project was for an MCU with 1.5 kB of code space and 67 bytes of RAM.)

Comment: @doynax: Some sort of PIC I would guess? A language "as-if" rule as described would be even more helpful on small micros than on big ones, since there are many cases where a compiler would be able to recognize expressions whose intermediate values could only overflow by a "little bit".  An expression like `a=(a+b)/2` where `a` and `b` are "unsigned 8-bit number" types and `a` is not `volatile` could be evaluated using three instructions (movf, addwf, rrf), using the rrf to shift back in the carry. In C, it would be necessary to cast to a 16-bit type before the addition.  Bulky and slow.